# Running one-off Cloud Foundry Tasks

Tags: continuous-integration, cloud-foundry, bamboo, swisscomdev

I use Bamboo CI to continuously build and push my app to the CF.
On every deployment i want to drop, migrate and seed my database.

If there are more than one instance the build sometimes fails, because Instance A tries to seed, when Instance B just dropped the database which obviously results in an error. The more instances the more likely it is that it fails.

I tried to create a "Cloud Foundry Task" Job in Bamboo, but it says that this job type is experimental and it throws an "Unkown Cloud Foundry Exception".

Is there another way to execute a script for only one instance or am I doing something wrong in bamboo?

Comment: CF tasks are not enabled on Swisscoms Application Cloud

Comment: Maybe this should be removed as possible choice in bamboo...

Comment: dear Timo Jokinen. Please use a search engine. This question was asked many times https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142184/why-does-the-cf-run-task-command-not-work-on-swisscom-cloudfoundry and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606065/cannot-run-cloudfoundry-task-unexpected-response-404. Do a little bit research before asking a question. Thanks.